# Alternative to using if statement in nginx location block

Tags: nginx, cache

Nginx config goal:

- Check if a certain cookie exists (doesn't matter what the value is)
- If it doesn't exist, include a particular config import.
- I only want to apply my rules to certain Locations, I cannot apply these conditionals to the global nginx configs. It's location specific.

**CURRENTLY, the config looks like this, and it's working well:**

```
  location ~ ^/somedestination\.php(/|$) {
    <... truncated other config lines for readability ...>

    include includes/xx-cache-config.conf;

    <... truncated other config lines for readability ...>

    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
  }
```

This server has many location blocks, and each `import` their own cache configs. This is a cgi only application, there is no direct try_files here.

So, in order to meet the above goals, I am experimenting with something like this, checking for existence of `$cookie_user` variable, and only applying my config if the cooke doesn't exist:

```
  location ~ ^/somedestination\.php(/|$) {

    # only include cache config if the cookie is null/empty
    if ($cookie_user = false) {
      include includes/xx-cache-config.conf;
    }

    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
  }
```

> > Seems logical, but here's the problem:
> > **I stumbled on this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/**

---

QUESTION: **If we shouldn't use `if` in a Location context (according to nginx official docs), how should I be doing this?**

---

**EDIT:** Here is the contents of what's being included from the conditional clause. **Currently** nginx is ALWAYS including this config, my goal right now is to *sometimes* not include it (when the cookie exists).

> Note: zone config itself is included elsewhere. This included config enables it.

**`includes/xx-cache-config.conf`**

```
fastcgi_cache CACHE_TLRS;

fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_resource_cache;

fastcgi_no_cache $no_resource_cache;

fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 48h;
fastcgi_cache_valid 302     4h;

fastcgi_cache_revalidate on;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale http_500 http_503 timeout updating;

fastcgi_cache_lock on;
fastcgi_cache_lock_age 15s;
fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 5s;

fastcgi_ignore_headers cache-control;

fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$host$uri";
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

Comment: `if` does have legitimate uses, but it really depends on what is in the file you included. You should add the contents of this file to the post.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. I've edited the original post with the requested information. The more I think about it, perhaps the `add_header` line could cause issues in the web app in the real world, I'll be sure the application tests for existence before assuming it'll be there.

Comment: Probably none of this needs to be in an `if`, and most of it can just be specified once in the `http` block or `server` block without including it multiple times. Why did you try to take this approach? It seems overly complicated. Do you have other configurations that you did not show?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes there is 6 different location blocks on this server and each have different cache config rules so are not defined at the server level. I tried to include the minimum to keep the question from being convoluted.

Comment: Also, there are some locations that we do not want **any** cache config set (we always want to hit php fresh, zero cache). This is a complex app with many different cache rules depending on what's being hit. Cache is not configured at the server level.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for sparking the idea that I was going about this wrong: you were right. Posted the answer below if you're interested in what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overthinking this.

After doing some reading, it seems imports are evaluated at server start, so you can't put them in a conditional.

So, I ended up utilizing the `fastcgi_cache_bypass` directive, I accomplished the goal without using `if` at all.

Modified the existing line
`fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_resource_cache;`

Changed it to: `fastcgi_cache_bypass $cookie_user $no_resource_cache;`

This will bypass cache if the variable(s) is not empty and not "0"

Doc link: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_bypass